# Extracting parts of text between specific delimiters from a large text file with custom delimiters and writing it to another file using Python

Tags: python, regex, text

I'm working on a project that involves creating a database of US federal code in a certain format. I've obtained the whole code form official source which is not structured well. I have managed to scrape the US Code in the below format into text files using some code on GITHUB.

```
-CITE-
    13 USC Sec. 1                                               1/15/2013

-EXPCITE-
    TITLE 13 - CENSUS
    CHAPTER 1 - ADMINISTRATION
    SUBCHAPTER I - GENERAL PROVISIONS

-HEAD-
    Sec. 1. Definitions

-STATUTE-
      As used in this title, unless the context requires another
    meaning or unless it is otherwise provided - 
        (1) "Bureau" means the Bureau of the Census;
        (2) "Secretary" means the Secretary of Commerce; and
        (3) "respondent" includes a corporation, company, association,
      firm, partnership, proprietorship, society, joint stock company,
      individual, or other organization or entity which reported
      information, or on behalf of which information was reported, in
      response to a questionnaire, inquiry, or other request of the
      Bureau.

-SOURCE-
    (Aug. 31, 1954, ch. 1158, 68 Stat. 1012; Pub. L. 94-521, Sec. 1,
    Oct. 17, 1976, 90 Stat. 2459.)


-MISC1-
                      <some text>

-End-


-CITE-
    13 USC Sec. 2                                               1/15/2013

-EXPCITE-
    TITLE 13 - CENSUS
    CHAPTER 1 - ADMINISTRATION
    SUBCHAPTER I - GENERAL PROVISIONS

-HEAD-
    Sec. 2. Bureau of the Census

-STATUTE-
      The Bureau is continued as an agency within, and under the
    jurisdiction of, the Department of Commerce.

-SOURCE-
    (Aug. 31, 1954, ch. 1158, 68 Stat. 1012.)


-MISC1-
                      <some text>

-End-
```

Each text file contains thousands of such blocks starting with a -CITE- tag and ending with an -END-.

Apart from these there are certain blocks which represent the start of a chapter or sub chapter and these do not contain a -STATUTE- tag.

E.g.

```
-CITE-
    13 USC CHAPTER 3 - COLLECTION AND PUBLICATION OF
           STATISTICS                                      1/15/2013

-EXPCITE-
    TITLE 13 - CENSUS
    CHAPTER 3 - COLLECTION AND PUBLICATION OF STATISTICS

-HEAD-
           CHAPTER 3 - COLLECTION AND PUBLICATION OF STATISTICS       


-MISC1-
                           SUBCHAPTER I - COTTON                       
    Sec.                                                     
    41.         Collection and publication.                           
    42.         Contents of reports; number of bales of linter;
                 distribution; publication by Department of
                 Agriculture.                                         
    43.         Records and reports of cotton ginners.                

       SUBCHAPTER II - OILSEEDS, NUTS, AND KERNELS; FATS, OILS, AND
                                  GREASES
    61.         Collection and publication.                           
    62.         Additional statistics.                                
    63.         Duplicate collection of statistics prohibited; access
                 to available statistics.                             

                   SUBCHAPTER III - APPAREL AND TEXTILES               
    81.         Statistics on apparel and textile industries.         

              SUBCHAPTER IV - QUARTERLY FINANCIAL STATISTICS          
    91.         Collection and publication.                           

                       SUBCHAPTER V - MISCELLANEOUS                   
    101.        Defective, dependent, and delinquent classes; crime.  
    102.        Religion.                                             
    103.        Designation of reports.                               

                                AMENDMENTS                            
      <some text>

-End-
```

I am interested only in those blocks that have a -STATUTE- tag.

Is there a way to extract only the blocks of text that have the -STATUTE- tag and write them to another text file?

I'm new to Python but I'm told this can be easily done in Python.

Appreciate if someone could guide me with this.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: First Analize structure of this file and paste format here. Then start writing code .

Comment: Basicaly, read(in_blocks) and parse the text. Then start parsing only from address that has wat you want so that you don't keep all text in memory.

Comment: @mgsk - I have no clue how this is done in Python, hence I turned to SO for help.

Comment: @cox - The file has multiple custom delimiters like -CITE-, -EXPCITE-, -STATUTE-, -MISC-, -MISC1-, etc holding text as shown above. Some blocks of text have the -STATUTE- tag and some don't I want to extract only those blocks that have a -STATUTE- tag and write to another file. Typical block starts with -CITE- and ends with -END- as shown above.

Comment: Here's the sample text file with hundreds of blocks of text - http://pastebin.com/YFQYELKh

Comment: Shown above is that it ends with `-End`, not `-END-`, but I think that's a minor issue.

Comment: @Alfe - yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd read the text line-by-line and parse it myself.  This way you can handle large input as streams.  There are nicer solutions using multiline regexps but those will always suffer from being not able to handle the input as a stream.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, re

# states for our state machine:
OUTSIDE = 0
INSIDE = 1
INSIDE_AFTER_STATUTE = 2

def eachCite(stream):
  state = OUTSIDE
  for lineNumber, line in enumerate(stream):
    if state in (INSIDE, INSIDE_AFTER_STATUTE):
      capture += line
    if re.match('^-CITE-', line):
      if state == OUTSIDE:
        state = INSIDE
        capture = line
      elif state in (INSIDE, INSIDE_AFTER_STATUTE):
        raise Exception("-CITE- in -CITE-??", lineNumber)
      else:
        raise NotImplementedError(state)
    elif re.match('^-End-', line):
      if state == OUTSIDE:
        raise Exception("-End- without -CITE-??", lineNumber)
      elif state == INSIDE:
        yield False, capture
        state = OUTSIDE
      elif state == INSIDE_AFTER_STATUTE:
        yield True, capture
        state = OUTSIDE
      else:
        raise NotImplementedError(state)
    elif re.match('^-STATUTE-', line):
      if state == OUTSIDE:
        raise Exception("-STATUTE- without -CITE-??", lineNumber)
      elif state == INSIDE:
        state = INSIDE_AFTER_STATUTE
      elif state == INSIDE_AFTER_STATUTE:
        raise Exception("-STATUTE- after -STATUTE-??", lineNumber)
      else:
        raise NotImplementedError(state)
  if state != OUTSIDE:
    raise Exception("EOF in -CITE-??")

for withStatute, cite in eachCite(sys.stdin):
  if withStatute:
    print "found cite with statute:"
    print cite
```

In case you want to process not `sys.stdin` you can do it like this:

```
with open('myInputFileName') as myInputFile, \
     open('myOutputFileName', 'w') as myOutputFile:
  for withStatute, cite in eachCite(myInputFile):
    if withStatute:
      myOutputFile.write("found cite with statute:\n")
      myOutputFile.write(cite)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Pardon my ignorance, so <stream> would be my input file, right? How can I write the output to another text file? Also, Here's a sample text file with hundreds of blocks of text starting with -CITE- and ending with -END- :  pastebin.com/YFQYELKh

Comment: Yes, `stream` is a parameter to the generator, in the use below I just pass `sys.stdin`, so you would just have to redirect input from that file.  On Unix that can be achieved by calling it on the command line like this:  `./myScript.py < inputFile`

Comment: This is good. thanks. But I need to extract all the blocks of text that have a -STATUTE- tag into a separate text file. how can I do that?

Comment: Redirect output to that file (`./myScript.py < inputFile > outputFile` on Unix) or open a file for writing before the loop and write into that.  I'll add that.  Just a moment.

Comment: Ooops.  Fixed a bug.  Use current version please.

Comment: Sure, trying it now.. basically I need to paste the whole code into a single <somoething.py> and run it with input file in the same dir, right?

Comment: Fixed some more minor issues.  Have it tested now with your input, works for me.

Comment: When run, the code gives me this error :   myOutputFile.write(print cite)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the below error when I run it after removing the for loop to print to stdin. Any idea what should be done differently to get the output?

Comment: Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Python.tmbundle/Support/sitecustomize.py", line 44, in tm_excepthook
    io = fdopen(error_fd, 'wb', 0)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/neo/cleanse.py", line 48, in <module>
    for withStatute, cite in eachCite(myInputFile):
  File "/Users/neo/cleanse.py", line 20, in eachCite
    raise Exception("-CITE- in -CITE-??", lineNumber)
Exception: ('-CITE- in -CITE-??', 350

Comment: Sorry, that `print` inside the `write()` was nonsense of course.  Fixed that.  And the `-CITE- in -CITE-` exception comes because you specified `-END-` but your actual input contains `-End-`. You will have to adjust that (I did here as well).

Comment: Awesome! Alfe - This gave me an output but not the desired one. The output I got is `-CITE-
    17 USC Sec. 102                                             01/03/2012 (112-90)

-EXPCITE-
    TITLE 17 - COPYRIGHTS
    CHAPTER 1 - SUBJECT MATTER AND SCOPE OF COPYRIGHT

-HEAD-
    Sec. 102. Subject matter of copyright: In general

-STATUTE-
found cite with statute:  `
Can we print out the output as below with actual text under -STATUTE- and not "found cite with statute".

Comment: Ideal output would be :  
`-CITE-
    17 USC Sec. 102                                             01/03/2012 (112-90)

-EXPCITE-
    TITLE 17 - COPYRIGHTS
    CHAPTER 1 - SUBJECT MATTER AND SCOPE OF COPYRIGHT

-HEAD-
    Sec. 102. Subject matter of copyright: In general

-STATUTE-  < actual text under -STATUTE- here >  
-SOURCE-
    (Pub. L. 94-553, title I, Sec. 101, Oct. 19, 1976, 90 Stat. 2544;
    Pub. L. 101-650, title VII, Sec. 703, Dec. 1, 1990, 104 Stat.
    5133.)


-MISC1-  <whatever present here too long to paste>                  -End-`

Comment: So basically, the script has to check if there's a -STATUTE- tag in the block between -CITE- and -End-; if yes - write the whole text between -CITE- and -End- of that text block to the output file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, that was another bug.  Use the most recent version in my answer above.  I fixed that in my own test and just forgot to add that fix here as well.  But it's quite simple:  There's a check at the beginning of the loop whether we are in state INSIDE and if so, we add the current line to the `capture`.  There we have to check instead whether we are in state INSIDE or INSIDE_AFTER_STATUTE, that's it.  see my patch above.

Comment: Absolutely amazing Al! I have tried this on 3 titles till now which have tens of thousands of blocks of text like this and the output is just perfect. I have a total of 51 titles to parse, I will ping you if I come across any glitch and once done I'll mark this as right answer. Thank you very much for your help here. have a wonderful day!

Comment: AL, one problem I'm encountering is that in some sections -STATUTE- tag exists but the there's no text under it or it is blank; mostly in such cases, the sections are either repealed or renumbered.  Can we tweak the code to ignore those blocks of code that have a STATUTE tag but have no text under it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So, for each line, if it starts with a hyphen, followed by some upper-case text, followed by another hyphen, then it's a marker that notes that we're in a new section of some sort. This can be done using a regular expression:

```
current_section_type = None
r= re.compile("^-([A-Z]*)-")
for line in f.readlines():
  m=r.match(line)
  if m:
    current_section_type = m.group(1)
  else:
    if current_section_type == "STATUTE":
      print line.strip()
```